# Can't see the "SQL Compact Server" on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation, sql-server-ce

i successfully installed the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, it works pretty nice.
Im trying to import an SQL Compact database (sdf) for a application i want to develop, the problem is, when im adding the "Connection" on "Server explorer" i doesn't give me the option to add an "SQL Compact"
I have also installed the VS2008, on that version it shows, but i wanted to do on VS2010, i installed the SQL Compact 3.5 and 4 for VS2010 but still the problem.

Also the "sqlcetoolbox" from codeplex doesn't work it gives me some weird errors when im trying to add an SQL Compact 3.5 or 4 on to my proyect.

My dvd of VS2010 doesn't come with a option for "SQL Compact" on Advanced Install when im on the setup.

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like SQL Server Compact is not properly installed. Go to about box in the Toolbox to check the status.

Comment: It doesn't appear on the About box the SQL Compact Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing SQL Compact with [nuget](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c).